# What attribute in the function barplot (graphics package)is used to adjust the label size on the horizontal axis in R?

Tags: r

I have a barplot where each 'bar' has a name on the x axis. However some of the labels with a lot of letters are being truncated from the bottom up(the end of the word is ok but the start is truncated). Does the function have an attribute where I can increase the label size.

Comment: From `?barplot`: `cex.names: expansion factor for axis names (bar labels)`.

Comment: thanks, the default is 'cex.names = par("cex.axis")' . What does the par do?